# Excel using index for a whole column except blank cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

Sorry I didnt know how to title this question so feel free to change it to make it more understandable. I have this values:

```
1   -   3
1   -   2
1   -   5
0   -   4
```

on my name manager I have these references:

range1:

```
=$B$2:INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(9.9E+307,$B:$B,1))
```

range2:

```
=$D$2:INDEX($D:$D,MATCH(9.9E+307,$D:$D,1))
```

This formula produces the best result, in this case 1-2:

```
=INDEX(range1,MATCH(MAX(range1-range2),range1-range2,0))&" - "&INDEX(range2,MATCH(MAX(range1-range2),range1-range2,0))
```

everything fine. However, it wont work if a row in between is blank like this:

```
1   -   3
1   -   2
1   -   5

0   -   4
```

is there anyway to fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: if you are just looking for a formula to get the last non-empty cell in a row (with blanks) try something like: `=MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH({"",-1E+307},A:A,-1)),MATCH({"",-1E+307},A:A,-1)))`

Comment: I want to take into account all the values of the column but ignoring the blank cells because at the time those are being counted as zero which is not the case.

Comment: you could change the `range2` to `IF(LEN(range2),range2,99999)` so every solution with an empty cell in `range2` will be -99999 (which never should be the best)